# Does second $match use index

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

From the MongoDB [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/):

> Place the $match as early in the aggregation pipeline as possible. Because $match limits the total number of documents in the aggregation pipeline, earlier $match operations minimize the amount of processing down the pipe.
>
> If you place a $match at the very beginning of a pipeline, the query can take advantage of indexes like any other db.collection.find() or db.collection.findOne().

Given the query

```
db.articles.aggregate( [ 
                    { $match : {date : {$gt: now, $lte: later } } },
                    { $match : { score : { $gt : 70, $lte : 90 } } },
                    { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
                   ] );
```

where (of course), now and later represent properly formatted dates,

Would the aggregation framework utilize an index for the second match (if it is available), or is only the first match in an aggregation pipeline eligible to use an index.

Would the query be perform better as:

```
db.articles.aggregate( [ 
                        { $match : {date : {$gt: now, $lte: later }, score : { $gt : 70, $lte : 90 } } },
                        { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
                   ] );
```

assuming an index exists that covers date and score?

Comment: Is it a compound index, if so then the prefix will stop it from working

Comment: Let's assume, for the sake of discussion, that the collection has an index on date and score individually, as well as date+score

Comment: I woudl assume since no group etc has occurred that MongoDB should use an index for both, however I am actually unsure how it is programmed in this way, it might not detect this, this is something really really internal, of course the latter query would be 100x better

Comment: Looks like we'll be getting `explain` for aggregation "soon": https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4504

Comment: @WiredPrairie Indeed will save looking through the source code for this, hopefully will be there very soon

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just put all the predicates in the original `$match`?  Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see why this would be necessary.  Any query that requires two `$match`es can be done with a single `$match`

Comment: @Mason I think it is more of just a questin of theory on that side, at least that's what I took it as, though it could also be index build up based...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, MongoDB (as of v2.4.6) will only use an index on the first `$match` in your pipeline.

For the second aggregation query you've posted, as long as you have a compound index on date and score, that index would get used for the query.  This should perform better than your first query.

Comment: Has this changed in v2.6? And also, if you have two matches following each other in the pipeline, eg `[{$match:{x:...}},{$match:{y:...}}]` and you have two separate indexes on x and y (and you can't have a compound index on x and y because x is, let's say, a multi-key index and y is a text index), could MongoDB use a different index for the different $match stages in the pipeline?